# Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-requests

I try to generate a random signal every random seconds from Raspberry Pi to a local WebServer in one dedicated Raspberry Pi (I would call it PiServer).

Then, PiServer will send the massage back to Raspberry Pi and also store a data in the MySQL Database.

Now I want to see how much time it take when increase the number of package send. So I run the following code (coffeeMaker.py) multiple times.

Here is my code

coffeeMaker.py contain in a client Raspberry Pi

```
from time import sleep
import requests
import datetime
import random

home = "A"
device = ["CoffeeModel01", "WashingMachine01", "RiceCooker01", "DryingMachine01", "MicrowaveModel01"]

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(0, 1)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 1)
    num3 = random.randint(0, 1)
    deviceNum = random.randint(0,4)
    code = "%d%d%d" % (num1, num2, num3)
    interval = random.uniform(2.0, 4.0)
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    payload = {"Device": device[deviceNum], "Code": code, "Time": format(timestamp), "Home": home}
    print "Data Sended : Device = " + device[deviceNum] + ", Code = " + code
    r = requests.post("http://160.18.2.109/HomeAuto.php", data=payload)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Failed to post data to server")
    print(r.text)
    sleep(interval)
```

HomeAuto.php contain in PiServer and using with SQL

```
<?php include "dbinfo.inc";

  /* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  $database = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE); 

  /* Get file from Raspberry Pi */
  $device = $_POST['Device'];
  $home = $_POST['Home'];
  $time = $_POST['Time'];
  $code = $_POST['Code'];

  /* Ensure that the Home table exists. */
  VerifyHomeTable($connection, DB_DATABASE, $home);

  $device = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $device);
  $home = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $home);
  $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $time);
  $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $code);

  if (strlen($device) || strlen($home) || strlen($time) || strlen($code)) {
    AddToLog($connection, $device, $home, $time, $code);
    AddToHome($connection, $device, $home, $time, $code);
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM $device Where Code=$code"); 

   while($query_data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       echo "Message : " . $query_data[1];
   }

/* Add an data to the AllLog table. */
function AddToLog($connection, $device, $home, $time, $code) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO `MainLog` (`Device`, `Code`, `Time`, `Home`) VALUES ('$device','$code','$time', '$home');";

   if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo "Error adding log data.";
}

/* Add an data to the Home table. */
function AddToHome($connection, $device, $home, $time, $code) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO `$home` (`Device`, `Code`, `Time`) VALUES ('$device','$code','$time');";

   if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo "Error adding log data.";
}

/* Check whether the table exists and, if not, create it. */
function VerifyHomeTable($connection, $dbName, $home) {
  if(!TableExists($home, $connection, $dbName)) { 
     $query = "CREATE TABLE `$home` (
         `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `Device` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
         `Code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
         `Time` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
         UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

     if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo "Error creating table.";
  }
}

/* Check for the existence of a table. */
function TableExists($tableName, $connection, $dbName) {
  $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $tableName);
  $d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $dbName);

  $checktable = mysqli_query($connection, 
      "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$t' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$d'");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($checktable) > 0) return true;

  return false;
}
?>
```

The problem is when I'm increasing the number of coffeeMaker.py up to 100 (run 100 files at the same time), some connection has been dropped and the log is shown like this

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='160.18.2.109', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /HomeAuto.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03EEB6D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

I want to know if the problem happen because of the WebServer (PHP file) or the bandwidth limited or the resource of PiServer.

Note: I've tried to using Amazon EC2 as a Server and also my laptop and the PiServer. And all have the same problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like a server issue . Thry decreasing the number of requests , or use a try - except block in `requests.post`

Comment: I've tried to use try - except handle already. But the question is, there're anyway to config the server side to receive more requests than this?